# How to check if the value of file handle is not null in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have this snippet in my script:

```
puts "Enter Filename:"
set file_name [gets stdin]

set fh [open $file_name r]

#Read from the file ....

close $fh
```

Now, this snippet asks user for a file name.. which is then set as an input file and then read. But when the file with the name `$file_name` doesn't exists, it shows error saying

```
illegal file character
```

How do i check if `fh` is not null (I don't think there is a concept of `NULL` in tcl being "everyting is a string" language!), so that if an invalid file_name is given, i can throw a print saying `file doesn't exists!`

Comment: Note that I added to the answer after you accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
try {
    open $file_name
} on ok f {
    # do stuff with the open channel using the handle $f
} on error {} {
    error {file doesn't exist!}
}
```

This solution attempts to open the file inside an exception handler. If `open` is successful, the handler runs the code you give it inside the `on ok` clause. If `open` failed, the handler deals with that error by raising a new error with the message you wanted (note that `open` might actually fail for other reasons as well).

The `try` command is Tcl 8.6+, for Tcl 8.5 or earlier see the long answer.

#### Long answer:

Opening a file can fail for several reasons, including missing files or insufficient privileges. Some languages lets the file opening function return a special value indicating failure. Others, including Tcl, signal failure by not letting `open` return at all but instead raise an exception. In the simplest case, this means that a script can be written without caring about this eventuality:

```
set f [open nosuchf.ile]
# do stuff with the open channel using the handle $f
# run other code
```

This script will simply terminate with an error message while executing the `open` command.

The script doesn't have to terminate because of this. The exception can be intercepted and the code using the file handle be made to execute only if the `open` command was successful:

```
if {![catch {open nosuchf.ile} f]} {
    # do stuff with the open channel using the handle $f
}
# run other code
```

(The `catch` command is a less sophisticated exception handler used in Tcl 8.5 and earlier.)

This script will not terminate prematurely even if `open` fails, but it will not attempt to use `$f` either in that case. The "other code" will be run no matter what.

If one wants the "other code" to be aware of whether the `open` operation failed or succeeded, this construct can be used:

```
if {![catch {open nosuchf.ile} f]} {
    # do stuff with the open channel using the handle $f
    # run other code in the knowledge that open succeeded
} else {
    # run other code in the knowledge that open failed
}
# run code that doesn't care whether open succeeded or failed
```

or the state of the variable `f` can be examined:

```
catch {open nosuchf.ile} f
if {$f in [file channels $f]} {
    # do stuff with the open channel using the handle $f
    # run other code in the knowledge that open succeeded
} else {
    # run other code in the knowledge that open failed
}
# run code that doesn't care whether open succeeded or failed
```

(The `in` operator is in Tcl 8.5+; if you have an earlier version you will need to write the test in another manner. You shouldn't be using earlier versions anyway, since they're not supported.)

This code checks if the value of `f` is one of the open channels that the interpreter knows about (if it isn't, the value is probably an error message). *This is not an elegant solution.*

**Ensuring the channel is closed**

This isn't really related to the question, but a good practice.

```
try {
    open nosuchf.ile
} on ok f {
    # do stuff with the open channel using the handle $f
    # run other code in the knowledge that open succeeded
} on error {} {
    # run other code in the knowledge that open failed
} finally {
    catch {chan close $f}
}
# run code that doesn't care whether open succeeded or failed
```

(The `chan` command was added in Tcl 8.5 to group several channel-related commands as subcommands. If you're using earlier versions of Tcl, you can just call `close` without the `chan` but you will have to roll your own replacement for `try ... finally`.)

The `finally` clause ensures that whether or not the file was opened or any error occurred during the execution of the `on ok` or `on error` clauses, the channel is guaranteed to be non-existent (destroyed or never created) when we leave the `try` construct (the variable `f` *will* remain with an unusable value, unless we unset it. Since we don't know for sure if it exists, we need to prevent the unset operation from raising errors by using `catch {unset f}` or `unset -nocomplain f`. I usually don't bother: if I use the name `f` again I just set it to a fresh value.).

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [error](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/error.htm), [in](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) operator, [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm), [unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm)

#### Old answer:

(This answer has its heart in the right place but I'm not satified with it these months later. Since it was accepted and even marked as useful by three people I am loath to delete it, but the answer above is IMHO better.)

If you attempt to open a non-existing file and assign the channel identifier to a variable, an error is raised and the contents of the variable are unchanged. If the variable didn't exist, it won't be created by the `set` command. So while there is no `null` value, you can either 1) set the variable to a value you know isn't a channel identifier before opening the file:

```
set fh {} ;# no channel identifier is the empty string
set fh [open foo.bar]
if {$fh eq {}} {
    puts "Nope, file wasn't opened."
}
```

or 2) `unset` the variable and test it for existence afterwards (use `catch` to handle the error that is raised if the variable didn't exist):

```
catch {unset fh}
set fh [open foo.bar]
if {![info exists fh]} {
    puts "Nope, file wasn't opened."
}
```

If you want to test if a file exists, the easiest way is to use the `file exists` command:

```
file exists $file_name

if {![file exists $file_name]} {
    puts "No such file"
}
```

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm)